# Using Set and Between in the same query to populate a table

Tags: sql-server

What I am trying to do is populate a row using a counter or some function of sql I am unaware of.

I can use

INSERT INTO EmpSkillsBridge
    (EmpIdFK , EmpSkillFK)
    Values 
    (1,1);

```
This updates one entire record I can even do it in batches of parentheses.
```

However since I am setting up a the table for the first time and since the data is for test (cough homework cough) reasons. I am trying make it so that the I can create a whole batch of data  I have 200 EmpID and 6 different skills. all I want right now is to make the first 25 EmpIdFK and the EmpSkillFK be (1,1)

If i use a where empIdFk < 26 I get an error. 
I tried using a loop but being new I got a little lost on how to implement

Then I read I could use the between statement. so my question is can I use a set statement in conjuction with between and make the code work that way?

Set into EmpSkillsBridge

(EmpIdFK , EmpSkillFK)
WHERE (EMPID BETWEEN 1 AND 26)

Values
(1,1);

would this be the best way to go around that?

Comment: I assume you are trying to populate empskillsbridge table, correct? If that is correct, the next question is - do you have 200 empid stored in one table and 6 skills stored in another table?

Comment: Yes I do. the table is a bridge and the values are a compound key on the bridge table

Comment: Do you already have data in empskillsbridge that you are wanting to update or are you trying to insert data?

Comment: trying to insert the data. its empty

Comment: Do you want to insert (1,1) 25 times or do you want to insert (1,1),(2,1),(3,1)...(25,1)?

Comment: (1,1) (2,1) (3,1) ....(25,1)    mostly so I can have some data in the table then be able to add the other skills later preferably using a similar query.

Comment: In the interim I made an excel sheet and imported the data from there that I wanted. I'm just curious if there Is a way to automate this using only sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Insert into EmpSkillsBridge
Select empid, 1
from employees 
where empid between 1 and 25;
```

Comment: Thank you kindly. I was way over thinking the issue

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:-

```
 insert into EmpSkillsBridge
 (EmpID, EmpSkillsFK)
 select empid, 1 from 
 (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by number) empid
    from master..spt_values
 ) v
 where empid between 1 and 25
```